# query in rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

In another question that i asked recently i got a really good answer and the code worked... But i do not know exactly why it works... Now i have a similar problem, but don't know how to solve it...?

What i have:

Models

```
users
questions (with answer_id)
answers
votes (with answer_id and user_id)
```

model for users:

```
has_many :questions
has_many :votes
def can_vote_on? (question)
    !question.answers.joins(:votes).where('votes.user_id = ?', id).exists?
  end

def voted_answer? (question)
   (what to do here...?) 
  end
```

model for questions:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:text].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

model for answers:

```
belongs_to :question
has_many :users, :through => :votes, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :votes
```

model for votes:

```
belongs_to :answer
belongs_to :user
```

In my question view i want to make a text bold when the current_used has voted on that specific answer. So how do i finish this:

```
<% for answer in @question.answers %>
 <% if current_user.voted_answer? (@question) %>
  <td>
   <strong><%= answer.text %></strong> 
  </td> 
 <% else %>
  <td>
   <%= answer.text %>
  </td> 
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thijs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want the opposite result of `can_vote_on?`, i.e. if a user cannot vote on an answer (`can_vote_on?` returns false), then it means that they already voted (`voted_answer?` should return true in this case) and vice versa.

One way to solve this is to have `voted_answer?` return the negation of `can_vote_on`:

```
def voted_answer? (question)
    !can_vote_on? question
end
```

Or of course you could use the query you used in `can_vote_on?` without the negation:

```
def voted_answer? (question)
    question.answers.joins(:votes).where('votes.user_id = ?', id).exists?
end
```

But I would prefer the first solution due to the DRY principle.

**UPDATE**

I was wrong about the negation. In this case you're dealing with a specific answer, not all of them.

In your model you'll want the following:

```
def voted_answer? (answer)
    answer.votes.where('votes.user_id = ?', id).exists?
end
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work... Now i get al the results bold, because the query checks if any of the votes.user_id exists... and i only wnat the current_user.id voted answer...

Comment: @Thijs - gotcha, I wasn't sure where id was coming from in that call. Have you tried substituting id with current_user.id in the second example I showed? I figured `can_vote_on?` was using the current user's id as well.

Comment: What i tried but i get undefined method errors all the time: def voted_on? (question)
    question.answers.joins(:votes).where('votes.user_id = ?', current_user.id)
  end

Comment: @Thijs - Do you have a `current_user` method defined anywhere? It looks like you don't.

Comment: I use devise, but current_user works in views... but not in my model... I allready got the problem solved on a more simple way... read the answer below.

Comment: @Thijs - More simple? Now you're throwing in a bunch of logic in the view, which is generally a less-preferred practice. If anything you could pass in the current_user.id from the view into the method.

Comment: Euhmm... i agree with you that logics don't belong in the view... not all of it... But can you then explain how you'd solve it? With a model? I'm also trying to get a count of all the votes per answer... Oh boy i thought i'd understand rails after reading railstutorial book and agile web dev. for rails..

Comment: I get this error: NoMethodError in Questions#show

Showing /home/thijs/rails_projects/rebasev2/app/views/questions/show.html.erb where line #35 raised:

undefined method `answer' for #<Question:0x9e637d8>
 I also put the following in my view: <% if current_user.voted_answer? (@question.answer) %>

Comment: Yeah `answer` is not defined on question, `answers` is. You want to pass in `answer` from the for loop, leave off `@question`: `<% if current_user.voted_answer? (answer) %>`

Comment: Yes it worked!! Thank you so much for the help!! Can you also explain how the method works? In the model...? I really want to learn it, copying code is handy, but i need to script lots more...!! Thanks!!

Comment: @Thijs - No problem I'm glad it worked. So in your view you're looping through all of the question's answers. You're then passing each answer into `voted_answer?`. This method takes the answer argument and gets its votes (through a db query), and then looks for any votes on that answer with the current_user's id. You can simply call "id" because it is a method available via any object, and since you're calling `voted_answer?` on the current_user, you're checking for the current_user's id. If a vote for that answer exists given the current_user, then you know that answer was the one chosen.

Answer (score 3):

you may do this

```
<% for answer in @question.answers %>
  <% if answer.votes.index{|vote| vote.user_id == current_user.id} %>
    <td>
    <strong><%= answer.text %></strong> 
    </td> 
  <% else %>
    <td>
    <%= answer.text %>
    </td> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

more logical variant create voted_by_user? function in class Answer

```
class Answer
  def voted_by_user?(user)
    voits.where('votes.user_id = ?', user.id).exists?
  end
end

<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <td>
    <% if answer.voted_by_user?(current_user) %>
      <strong><%= answer.text %></strong> 
    <% else %>
      <%= answer.text %>
    <% end %>
  </td> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow it worked voits needs to be votes... but can you explain why it worked??

Comment: Ok i get it!! You're comparing the vote.id with the answer_id from the vote.user_id

Comment: answer contains voits. voits refer user. And if current_user.id == voit.user_id - this is mean that this user voit for this answer

Comment: This code won't work, the OP doesn't have a model or method `voits` defined.